# Example of a periodic free resolution over a hypersurface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I'm reading "[HOMOLOGICAL ALGEBRA ON A COMPLETE INTERSECTION,
WITH AN APPLICATION TO GROUP REPRESENTATIONS](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1980-260-01/S0002-9947-1980-0570778-7/S0002-9947-1980-0570778-7.pdf)" by David Eisenbud

I'm wondering what would be a nice example illustrating Theorem 6.1 on page 52 of the document, where I get a periodic free resolution of $M$ after $d+1$ steps, and another example where I can see a periodic free resolution when $M$ is maximal Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: Cross posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4595497/884739

Comment: For instance, let $A = k[t]/t^2$, then $$\dots \to A \stackrel{t}\to A \stackrel{t}\to A \stackrel{t}\to A \stackrel{t}\to A \to k \to 0$$ is an example of 2-periodic (actually, even 1-periodic) resolution.

Comment: @Sasha thanks for your answer. Do you have any other example where the periodicity starts after "$d+1$" steps?

Comment: For the same $A$, e.g., you can replace $k$ by $A \oplus k$ and then periodicity will start from the second step. For a longer initial interval you need a more complicated ring.

Comment: But you can use the same idea: just add to $M$ another module that has a finite free resolution --- this will spoil the first steps keeping the rest unchanged.